# Visual Studio + Subsonic 3 + Multiple Projects + "transform all templates" problems

Tags: visual-studio-2008, subsonic3, t4

I am using

Visual Studio + Subsonic 3 + Multiple Projects + T4 Templates + "transform all templates" and I have two projects each with their own DB and associated activerecord.tt files etc.

Then I right click each tt file in select run custom tool - all is OK

BUT when I click on  "transform all templates" all hell breaks lose with weird errors about the tt templates

Has anyone used subsonic 3 with multiple projects with different databases ?

Thanks Mike

Comment: I'm having exactly the same problem.
Can't figure out what's is happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved this .... 
Solution Structure
   multiple projects with at least 2 separate Subsonic Data Access Layers for two different DBs

both the Subsonic had App.Configs with connection strings - with different names

i solved the problem by duplicating the connection strings in both App.config files

so each one contained connection string to both DBS

Now "transform all templates" works fine

Mike